# .lock file gets in the way when trying to generate Yeoman Chrome extension

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Just installed a clean copy of `yeoman` along with `generator-chrome-extension`. I ran it and all when well until I get to this step:

```
✔ pre-build test passed successfully!
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-jpegtran@0.1.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-optipng@0.1.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-gifsicle@0.1.1
npm ERR! EEXIST, open '/home/vagrant/.npm/5ac6bb0f-ant-npm-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: /home/vagrant/.npm/5ac6bb0f-ant-npm-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-30-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/Projects/test.dev/chrome/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/.npm/5ac6bb0f-ant-npm-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried deleting that .lock file but each time I'm given the error that it doesn't exist.

What could be causing this block and how can I get around it?

EDIT:
I figured out why I can't delete the file. The generator appends `.STALE` to the end. I deleted all the stale lock files just in case, but still no go. Why if it renamed it, is it somehow blocking the progression past this point?

Also, in answer to a question, the owner of `.npm` is `vagrant` and group is `vagrant`.

Answer (score 2):

Good news! See #6318 for details, but I now believe (with more confidence this time than last) that this issue has been addressed for real. npm -g install npm@2.1.1 or npm -g install npm@next will get you the fixed version of npm. If you run into additional problems, please open new issues, as the code that caused this issue is no longer in npm.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6309

Comment: Is there any chance you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/36312543/188474  ?  I can't get any traction.