# How do I Properly run NPM Install in Visual Studio Team Services Build Agent

Tags: npm, azure-devops

I'm having trouble setting up an NPM task for an automated build in Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online).  There are two problems:

1. Cache locking errors (shown below).
2. It is painfully slow -- 45+ minutes for a dozen or so packages.

I added the --cache argument but that did not seem to help.

```
npm install --dev --cache $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\b
```

The binaries folder seems like the right spot for the cache, but honestly, I'm not sure.  Some documentation here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables#AgentVariables

I appreciate any advice...

**Current Config:**

[image]

**Build console output:**

```
Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.97.1\tasks\Npm\0.2.7
##[debug]check path : C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.97.1\tasks\Npm\0.2.7\task.json
##[debug]set resource file to: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.97.1\tasks\Npm\0.2.7\task.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]check path : C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
##[debug]npm=C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
##[debug]cwd=C:\a\1\s\com.example.web
##[debug]path exists: C:\a\1\s\com.example.web
##[debug]command=install
##[debug]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd arg: install
##[debug]arguments=--dev --cache C:\a\1\b
##[debug]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd arg: --dev --cache C:\a\1\b
##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
##[debug]Arguments:
##[debug]   install
##[debug]   --dev
##[debug]   --cache
##[debug]   C:\a\1\b
[command]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd install --dev --cache C:\a\1\b
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated sf-lint@1.0.2: Use eslint-config-simplifield instead.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: Grunt needs your help! See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1403.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\a\1\s\com.example.web\@shinnn\eslint-config@>=0.0.5 <0.0.6\fixtures
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs@2.1.3: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Please update 'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt'
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency qunitjs@^1.14.0 included from karma-qunit will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN package.json Dependency 'mocha' exists in both dependencies and devDependencies, using 'mocha@*' from dependencies
npm WARN package.json Dependency 'mocha' exists in both dependencies and devDependencies, using 'mocha@*' from dependencies
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\a\1\s\com.example.web\@shinnn\eslint-config@>=0.0.4 <0.0.5\fixtures
> cson@1.6.2 preinstall C:\a\1\s\com.example.web\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-save-license\node_modules\grunt-replace\node_modules\applause\node_modules\cson
> node ./cyclic.js
npm WARN locking Error: EMFILE, open 'C:\a\1\b\_locks\strip-ansi-0bb45da2369f5768.lock.STALE.STALE.STALE'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  C:\a\1\b\_locks\strip-ansi-0bb45da2369f5768.lock failed { [Error: EMFILE, open 'C:\a\1\b\_locks\strip-ansi-0bb45da2369f5768.lock.STALE.STALE.STALE']
npm WARN locking   errno: -4066,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EMFILE',
npm WARN locking   path: 'C:\\a\\1\\b\\_locks\\strip-ansi-0bb45da2369f5768.lock.STALE.STALE.STALE' }
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--dev" "--cache" "C:\\a\\1\\b"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
2016-03-30T14:15:17.4509244Z npm ERR! Attempt to unlock C:\a\1\s\com.example.web\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-pngquant\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\compare-size\node_modules\ava\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\strip-ansi, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN locking Error: EMFILE, open 'C:\a\1\b\_locks\ansi-styles-cedcc1e1e4774cd0.lock.STALE.STALE.STALE'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  C:\a\1\b\_locks\ansi-styles-cedcc1e1e4774cd0.lock failed { [Error: EMFILE, open 'C:\a\1\b\_locks\ansi-styles-cedcc1e1e4774cd0.lock.STALE.STALE.STALE']
npm WARN locking   errno: -4066,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EMFILE',
npm WARN locking   path: 'C:\\a\\1\\b\\_locks\\ansi-styles-cedcc1e1e4774cd0.lock.STALE.STALE.STALE' }
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--dev" "--cache" "C:\\a\\1\\b"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! Attempt to unlock C:\a\1\s\com.example.web\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-pngquant\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\compare-size\node_modules\ava\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\ansi-styles, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN locking Error: EMFILE, open 'C:\a\1\b\_locks\has-ansi-819c7cca16ab7ac8.lock.STALE.STALE.STALE'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
2016-03-30T14:15:17.5709240Z npm WARN locking  C:\a\1\b\_locks\has-ansi-819c7cca16ab7ac8.lock failed { [Error: EMFILE, open 'C:\a\1\b\_locks\has-ansi-819c7cca16ab7ac8.lock.STALE.STALE.STALE']
```

Comment: I can't seem to find documentation on the --dev and --cache flags, could you give me some pointers?

Comment: Honestly, those flags should not be necessary -- see my answer below.  Updating NPM globally did the trick.

Comment: I see. I'm actually trying to avoid downloading all node_modules on every build and I thought this --cache flag would have helped.  I suppose installing npm globally solved your lock file issue but not the node_modules redownload issue?

Comment: Also trying to not have to install the node_modules folder on every build, and do not want them to be part of the artifacts. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Philip - Don't know, but I've found the MS build support team  to be super helpful.  From the build page, click help and then follow the support links until you log a ticket.  They're pretty responsive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re-installing NPM solved my issue:

npm install npm -g

Specifically, I added the circled task to my build:

[image: build image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your own answer :)

Comment: You can disable this build task to save time on future builds until it is needed again

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what is the difference in install time with and without this step?

Comment: I don't recall it being significant on subsequent runs.