# curl was not found in the path Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio, curl, azure-devops, alm

I'm using the Hosted Agent for release management in Visual Studio Team Services. I have a **cURL Upload Files** task on my release definition which was working last week and I've had several successful deployments over the past weeks.

Today I created a new release from the same release definition and I am receiving the following error on the **cURL Upload Files** task.

```
2016-03-31T08:56:43.4253012Z ##[debug]curl=null
2016-03-31T08:56:43.4263027Z ##[error]curl was not found in the path.
2016-03-31T08:56:43.4303022Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2016-03-31T08:56:43.4313025Z Return code: 1
```

I have checked the System Capabilities on the Hosted Agent and it lists **curl C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl.exe** as one of them.

Any one have any ideas why this has suddenly started failing?

Comment: FWIW I also just experienced this...we should likely submit a ticket...somewhere...

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/support-overview-vs

But I suspect it will resolve soon...

Comment: The ticket actually worked.  I've found MS online support to be pretty responsive. I think I'll submit another to get NPM updated...

http://stackoverflow.com/q/36312543/188474

Comment: Yes I created a ticket too. Had a response within a few hours directing me to the url you supplied. They said to wait until the issue was resolved and then retry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, sorry about this.  I'm with the product team and we’ve confirmed this is a regression on our side.  cURL is still on the box but it is no longer in the path.  We’re working on getting this fixed on our end but it’ll likely take a day or two.  In the meantime, we’d recommend doing the following:

1. Before your curl task, create a new powershell task
2. Change the type of the task to be an “Inline Script”
3. Change the Inline Script input to be the following:

`echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]$env:PATH;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"`

4. Save and queue a new build.

---

UPDATE: We've fixed this issue now.  The workaround should be no longer necessary.

Comment: This workaround works.  Is this something that we can leave and forget about, or will we need to remove the workaround in the future?

Comment: It should be completely fine to leave this in place.  It wouldn't hurt to remove it either in about a week.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TaylorLafrinere I see that the support page is reporting everything is now ok. However on retrying the release again this morning, I'm still getting the same error. I will try your workaround.

Comment: The above workaround has worked for me also, thanks.