# VSO build task: curl not found

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops, ms-release-management

I have a VSO Release Management set up to deploy to an Azure App. I hava curl build task to upload my web.config file after replacing the tokens in the file. This task which has been working fine for the past 2 weeks has suddenly started failing and causing my release management process to fail. I get the following error messages.

### [error]curl was not found in the path.

### [error]Task cURLUploader failed. This caused the job to fail.

The same failure has happened on 2 different team projects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329107/curl-was-not-found-in-the-path-visual-studio-team-services):

Taylor has confirmed they are fixing this issue now. As a workaround, use the steps below:

1. Before your curl task, create a new powershell task
2. Change the type of the task to be an “Inline Script”
3. Change the Inline Script input to be the following:

> echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]$env:PATH;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\bin"

4. Save and queue a new build.