# curl path was not found in the path Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: curl

I am using VSTS for Build and Release pipeline.
For one of the deployment script i am using curl command, it was working fine for last 1 month but suddenly i am getting error.
Error Message:
"The term 'curl.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

They recently updated their visualstudio.com online serivces.
I also relied on curl.exe, and it's missing.

I think they might have phased it out.

A less popular alternative might be to use [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329107/curl-was-not-found-in-the-path-visual-studio-team-services) duplicate for a solution